# How does Forge Viewer interacts with the local repository (json files)?

Tags: json, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I need to implement some customization to the autodesk viewer, and to do that I need to understand how the relationships with the repository files work, to understand these relationships I'm also using the model.sdb provided by forge derivative-api (the same which gives us the json files).

I have identified 6 files:

```
objects_ids.json.gz
objects_attrs.json.gz
objects_avs.json.gz
objects_vals.json.gz
objects_offs.json.gz
objects_viewables.json.gz
```

Some of this files are pretty simple to understand:

**objects_ids.json.gz** - This file has the same content as the _objecs_id table, basically the external id and dbids (which is the row number -1).

**objects_attrs.json.gz** - Again this file is equivalent to a table on the sdb database, very easy to read. Here we have the definition for the attributes used in the modelviewer. It has the following "columns": id,name,category,data_type,data_type_context,description,display_name,flags,display_precision

**objects_vals.json.gz** Equivalent to _objects_val table, here we have two things, ID and VALUE (for the attributes defined on the previous json document).

Until now things are pretty easy... We have the object identification, attributes and it's possible values, but the problem is, how to make then work together? Right now they are isolated, so they're useless right now. I need to relate a object identification with it's attributes with it's values.

To do that in the model.mdb we can join the tables, with the main relationship table: _objects_eav
It has the entity_id, the attribute_id and value_id. So to join the data and have the information we need we can simply do:

```
`SELECT * FROM _objects_id
INNER JOIN _objects_eav ON _objects_id.id = _objects_eav.entity_id
INNER JOIN _objects_attr ON _objects_attr.id = _objects_eav.attribute_id
INNER JOIN _objects_val ON _objects_val.id = _objects_eav.value_id`
```

But there is no json file equivalent to the _objects_eav table...

Instead we have the following files
**objects_avs.json.gz, objects_offs.json.gz, objects_viewables.json.gz**

Right now I have no idea how to merge the data between these files and get the whole information needed. Any toughs about this?

Other thoughts:
Alternatively I could use the model.sdb to access the data, but I rather use the JSON, since they are way smaller (30 x smaller than the model.sdb, that's a massive amount).

I could also get some data using the methods provided by the viewer objects in JavaScript, but then I would be stuck with the methods and properties provided by the viewer, and unfortunately they do not fulfill all my requirements.

Then there is the option to use the model-derivative API, but one of my requirements is to be able to work with the data disconnected (offline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the individual .json.gz files contain:

- `objects_ids.json.gz` - object IDs
- `objects_offs.json.gz` - for each object ID at the same index in `objects_ids.json.gz`, this array defines an offset into the attribute-value list in `objects_avs.json.gz`
- `objects_avs.json.gz` - contains attribute-value pairs which are basically offsets into `objects_attrs.json.gz` and `objects_vals.json.gz`
- `objects_attrs.json.gz` - contains different attributes (and their metadata I believe)
- `objects_vals.json.gz` - contains de-duplicated values

With that said, I'd still suggest to use the sqlite format (even though it's bigger), instead of the proprietary .json.gz files as those are really meant to be used by the Forge Viewer and could potentially change in the future.

Comment: Btw. here's a piece of code in my (unofficial) Forge SDK module that shows how the `objects_*.json.gz` files can be parsed: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-server-utils/blob/develop/src/svf/propdb-reader.ts

Comment: Thanks Petr! Very nice, I going to make good use of your repository.
About Forge changing the format, I find it very unlikely to do so without affecting the database schema. If they need to change the json, they almost certainly need to change the database schema too. So if they are changing anything related to this, I will need to update my code anyways. Also Forge still uses R71 of threejs, which points me to the direction that Forge doesn't like making breaking changes, which is good.

Comment: Hello again, unfortunatly I've found a critical bug on your code. 
In the file objects_attrs.json.gz we have many duplicates of the fist column, (values in the first column, more precisely the name of the attr is not unique) meaning that your code only exposes the last attr with the duplicated/triplicated name.

Comment: For example, in my very small .svf file, made with a sample project for revit 2020, I count 3 attrs with the name = "Level".

I´ve two attrs "Level" with category = "Constraints".

The only diference between the last two is the column flags, (0 for the first, 8 for the second attr)

 That is true even for the sdb database, so its not a problem with the json files.

Why does this data is duplicated? How can I know which is the correct property to use?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @GabrielMarcondes. Yes, some of the attributes are internal (those with attribute category starting and ending with two underscores, for example, "\_\_child\_\_"). I've updated the code to make it easier to differentiate the public vs internal properties: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils/blob/develop/src/common/propdb-reader.ts#L51-L67.

Comment: Humm, that's nice but I still have the problem with the attr named "Level", the categories are: "Constraints", only the "Flag" column makes the row unique, besides the ID. They have not underscores anywhere. But thanks anyway you were very helpfull, my main issue was how to relate the files and you've done that flawlessly, now I can work in my own structure. (Basically I'm going to store an array inside the values, so I wont miss anything.) Thanks for your work and your availability.

Comment: Hey @Petr Broz , I'm receiving an error at line 44, on this file:
https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils/blob/develop/src/common/propdb-reader.ts#L51-L67

An index out of bounds exception.
Could you please take a look on it again?

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue with any of my sample files. Would you mind sharing a URN or an SVF file for me to test?

Comment: Sure, perhaps it would be better for me to make a new question, what do you think?

Comment: Sure, or perhaps send your question and sample file directly to our support email: forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com. I can take it from there.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting my work day now so I'll try to solve this by myself first, probably it's something I did wrong, if your untouched code presents the same behavior I'll send you an e-mail. Thanks for your kindness Petr.